# Scala the index of a number in which interval of an array

Tags: arrays, scala, for-loop, scala-collections

Suppose I have an array of `(0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 1)` and I have a number `0.15`, I'd hope to get the index of that. Since `0.15 > 0.1` and `0.15 < 0.2`, it is in the interval `2`. Is there a state-of-art way to do that? Currently I use a for loop with a var variable and go through each interval but I do not think it's the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming the array is ordered you can try:

```
arr.indexWhere(_ >= 0.15) - 1
```

if there is no such instance you get - 2.

Comment: It works but there is a little bit further modification for boundaries. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array elements are in ascending order, you can define a simple function to compose an array with the inserted element as follows:

```
def insert(a: Array[Double], x: Double): Array[Double] = {
  val i = a.indexWhere(_ >= x)
  if (i >= 0) a.take(i) ++ Array(x) ++ a.drop(i) else a ++ Array(x)
}

val a = Array(0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)

insert(a, 1.5)
res1: Array[Double] = Array(0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 1.5)

insert(a, 3)
res2: Array[Double] = Array(0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 3.0)

insert(a, -0.1)
res3: Array[Double] = Array(-0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5)
```

Comment: Instead of `take(i)` and `drop(i)` you can use `a.patch(i,Array(x),0)`.